# Clarity on interface usage in my code

Tags: c#

I have used an interface to supply 2 values i.e `ID` and `Name` to classes `Employee` and `Student`. Thereafter I have used a function of type interface to choose which of these 2 class' object should be chosen and then in `Main()`, supplied the values. Now the point is, I want to use these values in a function in `Employee` class. But somehow I am not getting, how to access this function because the object being of type interface will not allow me to access the object & if I make a new object, values that I supplied are no more there. So what is the right way of doing it. Plz help!

```
interface IData
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class Employee : IData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public void getDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Emp"+ID);
    }
}

class Student : IData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Choice
{
    public IData Fetch(bool Flag)
    {
        if (Flag == true)
        {
            Employee em = new Employee();
            return em;
        }
        else
        {
            Student st = new Student();
            return st;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Choice ch=new Choice();
        IData idata = ch.Fetch(true);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter ID and Name:");
        idata.ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        idata.Name = Console.ReadLine();

        //Console.WriteLine("Id={0} & Name={1}", idata.ID, idata.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(idata.GetType());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to work with your `idata` as an `Employee` object?

Comment: @Dan I am asking, how to access employee member method while supplying value from idata object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your `IData` object as an `Employee` object, you have to cast it.  You should, of course, check to make sure that that cast will make sense.

Using your example program, you could do something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Choice ch=new Choice();
    IData idata = ch.Fetch(true);
    Console.WriteLine("Enter ID and Name:");
    idata.ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    idata.Name = Console.ReadLine();

    var employee = idata as Employee;
    if (employee != null)
    {
        employee.getDetails();
    }
    //Console.WriteLine("Id={0} & Name={1}", idata.ID, idata.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(idata.GetType());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

using the `as` operator here and testing for null will both check if your object is actually an `Employee` and cast it to that if it is.  You could do a direct cast (e.g. `((Employee)idata).getDetails()`, but that will run the risk of throwing an exception if the cast fails (and it could fail because you made a mistake or because future implementers of `IData` behave in ways you don't anticipate right now).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was thinking of casting but somehow it just didn't strike the right cord. But yes, the code works just fine. thanks again. Can you suggest any better way of working through this problem?

Comment: This is a pretty typical pattern - although it might be better to have better names for your interfaces (`IPerson`?  `IPersonWithIdentifier`?).  Anyway, glad to help - consider marking this as the accepted answer and/or upvoting if it was helpful.

Comment: Absolutely, I can't upvote because I am low on reputation points but have marked as accepted answer, thanks again.